# Как правильно писать: "от" или "из-за"?

Tags: выбор-слов

*Могут ли ноги деформироваться из-за (от) ношения слишком тесных скальных туфель?*

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере допустимы *оба* варианта, но предлог "*от*" более естественен для контекста с *нейтральным* указанием на причину (у тех, кто носит узкие туфли, ноги могут от этого деформироваться). Предлог "из-за" (чего, кого) придаёт причине *негативный* оттенок, а в нашем случае это было уместно в контексте выяснения причины чего-то конкретно случившегося (мол, пациент сам виноват, это произошло из-за него самого).

В *общем* же случае предлоги **не** взаимозаменяемы (по грамматическим или по стилистическим причинам):

> Мы не пошли за грибами **из-за** плохой погоды.
>
> **Из-за** него мы пришли не туда.
>
> Он прыгал **от** радости.
>
> **От** этого все выиграют.
>
> **Из-за** этого ничего не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Оба предлога могут указывать на причину. В этом смысле они синонимы. Выбрать можно любой. Каждый из вариантов правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что *"деформироваться **от** ношения"* звучит гораздо проще и естественней, поэтому предлог *"от"* в данном случае гораздо больше подходит. Зачем усложнять?

Примеры в Нацкорпусе пусть не всегда очень явно, но всё же говорят в пользу выбора *"от".* Так, лексико-грамматический поиск глаголов в разной форме с этими предлогами подряд дал следующие результаты: *деформироваться от/из-за* — 7/3, *повредиться от/из-за* — 4/1 и, наконец, *износиться от/из-за* — 4/0. Я брал также и эти глаголы, так как считаю, что выбор предлога для них аналогичен выбору для исходного глагола "деформироваться". Разницы большой не вижу.